# SQL in Oracle: Stop reformulation of nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, database-performance

Hello all :) I need Oracle to understand that a nested query needs to stay nested, for performance issues.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(clients_me.address, clients_them.address) jw,
    clients_them.*,
    clients_me.* 
  FROM clients_them JOIN clients_me ON clients_me.email = clients_them.email
) WHERE jw > 80
```

Performance is fine without the last `WHERE jw > 80`. My understanding is that Oracle tries to add the JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY in the join inside the nested query. I just want to filter some bad matches.

Best regards

Comment: Are you only selecting the Top N rows in your application?  These types of changes can often make the first N rows return faster, but retrieving the entire data set is as slow or worse.

Comment: I'd remove JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY from query and see how ot performs first joining clients_them.* and clients_me.*...

Comment: Uh, for performance reasons, I'd look at the use of your stored proc; there's only so much an optimizer can do if you have to compute something for every single row after all.  Perhaps do _another_ nesting level?  Also, given that the [range seems to be from 0 through 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance), are you sure your use of `80` is correct (ie, I'd be using a decimal)?

Comment: Please show us the execution plan of both queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting some hints such as `NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION`, or maybe `NO_PUSH_SUBQ` or `NO_MERGE`. (I'm not an expert with hints, plus I think most of the times it's good to avoid them).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements006.htm#BABCGJDI

But IMHO, the best thing to do would be to get the execution plan of you bad performing query, so you'd know what is not happening as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I tried various combination and positions of these hints (plus others from your link) to no avail. None would stop oracle to act the way I want. I ended up with building a temporary table. This is not the right thing to do, but I'm validating your answer, as I deeply believe it is possible to make oracle behave with the right hints.

Answer (score 1):

Push_pred / no_push_pred: If you have a non-mergeable view (possible because of a no_merge hint) in your query, how should you operate the join from other tables; should you create one large view result and join it once (no_push_pred) or should you push the join predicate down into the view definition and recreate the view result set for every driving row from another table (push_pred).

It means push_pred vailid only for no_merge.
please try add hint as below:

```
/*+ no_merge(y) no_push_pred(y) */
```